# Is there a better phrase for something that is new/inspiring?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am new to English StackExchange so please let me know if there's anything to be aware of.

I'm looking for a better word or phrase that can describe something that is new/inspiring/ - specifically, something that lets me see a new aspect of matters.

Comment: Probably “epiphany” is the term you are looking for: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/epiphany

Comment: Hi I think the word enlightening works best, although it's not the most upvoted answer.

Comment: Something you should be aware of: you should give an example sentence in which the desired word is indicated by —————.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "see a new aspect of matters", a little light may help ;-). An entire [epoch was named after the first word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Enlightenment):

**Enlightening** or **illuminating**.

Answer (score 3):

Consider "revelation" or "revelatory."  The [Oxford Dictionary as quoted by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+revelation) offers a definition of "revelation" that's relevant to the sense I mean:

> used to emphasize the surprising or remarkable quality of someone or something.
>
> *"seeing them play at international level was a revelation"*

[Dictionary.com offers some sample sentences](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/revelatory) and I think they have just the sense you're looking for:

> Few families are covered as exhaustively as the House of Windsor, but this trio of mononyms delivered a truly revelatory, once-in-a-generation interview whose repercussions we’ll likely feel for years to come.
>
> THE 10 BEST TV SHOWS FROM THE FIRST HALF OF 2021|INKOO KANG|JULY 1, 2021|WASHINGTON POST

> Even with the restriction of having to play or sing to the midi track, it still felt revelatory.
>
> A MUSICAL POSTCARD TO MIT GRADUATES|FREDERICK HARRIS JR.|AUGUST 24, 2021|MIT TECHNOLOGY REVIEW

> These are full of variety and of actual novelty, now of startling discord, now of revelatory beauty.
>
> CONTEMPORARY AMERICAN COMPOSERS|RUPERT HUGHES

Answer (score 3):

You might like [revelation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revelation) defined by Merriam Webster online as (among other definitions)

> a usually secret or surprising fact that is made known

The word is closely associated with Christian theology, usually referring to the making available by God to Man of truths about Himself or the world and its workings. However it does have secular meanings, particularly in terms the making known of negative facts about people organisations but MW also defines [Come as a revelation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20as%20a%20revelation) as

> to be a pleasant often enlightening surprise

This means that *came as a revelation to me* might well suit your case

Comment: I was working on this answer when Casey posted his answer. We obviously had the same thought (or possibly revelation)

Comment: I find it strange how many dictionaries seem to neglect this sense of the word or put "come as a revelation" as a separate, fixed phrase... had to try a few dictionaries before I found the sense I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say "novel", but I see that LPH beat me to it. :) Other options include "eye-opening" and "astonishing". If you look up any of these terms in a thesaurus, you'll get several more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

**Path-breaking** appears to be the word you're looking for:

> completely different and new and affecting the way in which things are done or considered in the future

*May's **path-breaking** essay 'The Recovery of American Religious History' was published in the American Historical Review in 1964.*

[Collins Dictionary]

Comment: I can't recall ever hearing that word in the UK — though it seems to be equivalent to [_ground-breaking_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ground-breaking) (which is common here).

Answer (score 0):

I like "epiphany". Wikipedia describes it as: "An epiphany (from the ancient Greek ἐπιφάνεια, epiphanea, "manifestation, striking appearance") is an experience of a sudden and striking realization."
Similar to Roman "Eureka!". Or: "Oh, man, so that's how it works." Having one is often quite amazing.  I have a job where I repair electronic equipment, and there are a lot of very talented engineers who come up with clever solutions. I have to repeat their epiphanies to fix some of them.  Keeping an open mind and understanding basic functions are your best tools to do that. You're doing fine - Good grammar & spelling are a good start.

Answer (score -1):

A term you might find appropriate is "*novelty*".

> **novelty** noun   BrE /ˈnɒvlti/  AmE /ˈnɑːvlti/ (plural novelties) ​[uncountable]
> the quality of being new, different and interesting
> ♦ It was fun working there at first but the novelty soon wore off (= it became boring).
> ♦ There's a certain novelty value in this approach.
> ♦ We must not mistake novelty for originality and quality.

- I need novelty in my life, I feel that only that would increase my stamina.